# Error: he path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

The code below automates browsers using Selenium.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\trainee\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https:\\www.google.com");
    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String str=driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println(str);
    String abc=driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(abc);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Gmail");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).submit();
}
```

When I execute the code, I get this Error:

> java.illegalstateexception: The path to the driver executable must be
>   set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property".

I gave the correct path in the code of the chrome driver which is installed in the system, even though I am facing this issue. Please help me with this.

Comment: can you also add error trace?

Comment: are you using chrome browser or ie browser, as per you question it is ie browser but in code it is chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Place the driver in some location like C:\Selenium\iexploredriver.exe. You can download IE driver from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Then

```
File file = new File("C:/Selenium/iexploredriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

in this line ---->
"System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\trainee\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");
Remove extension(.exe) from path of chrome driver

try this line with remove .exe extension

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\trainee\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver");

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of handleing this is to add the path to your webdriver executable into your PATH environment variable.

This way, you don't have to worry about where is the driver executable from your code, but rather from environment configuration.

In case of chrome and firefox, being portable on windows, mac and linux, you could just run your selenium code on any of the above OS's without specifying the path to your driver but correctly configuring the environment that you will run your tests on (putting the path to the executable in the PATH env var).